# gethostname silently truncates result instead of giving ENAMETOOLONG error

Tags: c, macos

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buf[4];
  int err = gethostname(buf, 4);
  printf("name: %s n: %d\n", buf, err); // BUG: err should be -1, and errno should give ENAMETOOLONG
  return 0;
}
```

on OSX, this gives:
`name: xyz n: 0`

even though my hostname is larger than 3; instead I would expect err to be -1 and errno to be `ENAMETOOLONG`;

note that this can also give rise to buffer overflow errors in case user isn't aware of this bug and would expect err to be -1 when buffer was too short (docs say that `\0` isn't written to buffer if buffer is too short), so printf as above is unsound even with err == 0. I've observed this while investigating https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/18088.

is that a bug? if so, where to report it?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the specification for the `gethostname` function. Read it again.

Comment: how do you interpret this? 
`[ENAMETOOLONG]     The current host name is longer than namelen.  (For gethostname() only.)`

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see the message contradicting the documentation.

Comment: my hostname has length 23; I'm passing `namelen = 4` which is < 23, so I'd expect the API to fail (err = -1) and errno to be set to ENAMETOOLONG; instead I'm getting err = 0. What am I mis-understanding here?

Comment: Documentation error, perhaps.  The behaviour of the [linux equivalent](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) is different.

Comment: I was expecting [POSIX behavior](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gethostname.html) and made assumptions -  my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The macOS manual says:

> ERRORS
> The following errors may be returned by these calls:
> …
> `[ENAMETOOLONG]` The current host name is longer than namelen.  (For gethostname() only.)

It also documents:

> Host names are limited in length to {`sysconf(_SC_HOST_NAME_MAX)`} characters, not including the trailing null, currently 255.

The manual also mentions `{_POSIX_HOST_NAME_MAX}`.

See also the POSIX specification of [`gethostname()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gethostname.html) which says:

> The `gethostname()` function shall return the standard host name for the current machine. The `namelen` argument shall specify the size of the array pointed to by the name argument. The returned name shall be null-terminated, except that if `namelen` is an insufficient length to hold the host name, then the returned name shall be truncated and it is unspecified whether the returned name is null-terminated.
>
> Host names are limited to `{HOST_NAME_MAX}` bytes.
>
> …
>
> Host names are limited to {HOST_NAME_MAX} bytes.

You should be taking steps to avoid using a string that is too short, and using [`sysconf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html) is one way to do so.

Since POSIX doesn't specify any errors, it is not clear that you have a bug to report, though I agree that the man page implies that you should get an `ENAMETOOLONG` error.

Comment: I don't understand how this explains the behavior I'm observing; all it says is that the maximum possible host name length is `sysconf(_SC_HOST_NAME_MAX)`; the man page says the API should give ENAMETOOLONG if `The current host name is longer than namelen`, which is the case in my example (namelen = 4, yet my hostname length is > 10), yet the API call gives err = 0

Comment: the call returns 0 because the hostname was actually found.  C does not hold your hand so you have to assure buffer sizes, etc